# How can I pop a navigation view and return to the previous view rather than the root view SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ContentView` that is the root view that navigates to a `DetailView.` The `DetailView` has a `navbaritem` that navigates to `Help2` view. **I want to click a button to dismiss the `Help2` view and return to the `DetailView`** (the view from which `Help2` came from).

Currently, when I press a button on the `Help2` view, it dismisses the view, but it returns me to the root `ContentView` rather than `DetailView`. If I navigate to the `Help2` view then manually click the back button to navigate to `DetailView`, it will go to `DetailView`. Then, if I immediately click on the `navbaritem` to get back to the `Help2` view, then click the button to dismiss the view, it will go to `DetailView` instead of `ContentView` as expected.

**ContentView**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Show Detail View")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**DetailView**:

```
struct DetailView: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        })
        {
            Text("Root")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("DetailView", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        NavigationLink(destination: Help2()){
            Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.medium)
        }
    )
  }
}
```

**Help2**:

```
struct Help2: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    })
        {
            Text("DetailView")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this would help you with what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317657/11974184

Comment: I updated my title. I am actually looking for a SwiftUI answer, thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution may be to move `NavigationLink` outside the `.navigationBarItems`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
            {
                Text("Root")
            }
        }
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: Help2(), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        )
        .navigationBarTitle("DetailView", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.isLinkActive = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.medium)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, worked perfectly! Any idea why what I had has strange behavior?

Comment: @jh95 It looks like a bug in SwiftUI. If you place a NavigationLink in the body it works as expected. Just putting it inside `navigationBarItems` causes problems.