# App freeze on swipe to right on WkWebview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using NavigationLink with NavigationBarButtons inside. App freeze when I am presenting Wkwebview on swipe to right.

I figure out that when I am not adding button on navigation-bar everything works fine.

```
  NavigationLink(destination:WebView(article:new,htmlString: new.post_content ?? "")
                            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                HStack{
                                    Button(action:{
                                        guard let url = URL(string:new.link ?? "") else { return }
                                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)}){
                                            Text("Original link")
                                                .font(.custom("Muli", size: 17))
                                    }
                                    Button(action:{  guard let url = URL(string:new.link ?? "") else { return }
                                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)}){
                                            Image("arrow_right")
                                                .font(.headline)
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        )
```

Comment: There might be a bug with opening links/urls directly from the `.navigationBarItems` - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63358275/8697793) describes a similar problem.

Comment: It is behaving the same when I remove link/url.